# My Windows 7 HP laptop's touchpad mouse not working

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse, touchpad

I have multiple computers and one of them broke so now I'm using other one. It is Windows 7 HP with a touchpad mouse, but now the mouse is not working. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

On most laptops there is a function key which enables and disables the touchpad. Usually this is represented along the function keys across the top of the keyboard. Try using 'fn' and one of the top function keys.

EDIT: Could you also provide the model of your laptop please?

Comment: Thanks for putting in so much time into answering two of my questions, but I solved it.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you resolved the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by pressing the tiny button on the touchpad in the right top corner.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the my Mouse driver in Device Manager. And my mouse touchpa wasn't working either. External usb mouse was working though.

My unexpected Solution:
If you have Linux, run that, my mouse touchpad was working in Linux. Then return back to Windows. It started working there too. And now, I can see the mouse driver under device manager as well.

Hope it helps.